# null value when i opened the php script in IE

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am trying to fetch the values from mysql table based on the certain values. below is my php script where i am getting json values from android and then parse it to array the passing array in to the select query.

So, when i open the script in IE i am getting values as null instead of []. What is wrong here.

**php**

```
<?php
$username = "xxxxx"; 
$password = "xxxxxx";   
$host = "localhost";
$database="xxxxxx";

$server = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
$connection = mysql_select_db($database, $server);

$JSON_received = $_POST["JSON"];

$obj = json_decode($JSON_received,true);

foreach ($obj['ilist'] as $key => $value) 
    {
        //echo "<br>------" . $key . " => " . $value;
        $im[] = $value;
    }


$myquery = "SELECT * FROM Movies WHERE im_rat IN ('$im')";

$query = mysql_query($myquery);

if ( ! $query ) {
    echo mysql_error();
    die;
}    


for ($x = 0; $x < mysql_num_rows($query); $x++) {
    $data[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
}

echo json_encode($data);     

mysql_close($server);

?>
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: If you're just opening the file then `$_POST["JSON"]` will be empty. You need to send a `POST` request to your script or hard code what `$_POST["JSON"]` should be if this is just for testing purposes.

Comment: I am passing JSON object from android to here using ContentValues.